# How could I take an instance of class in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It is a class which instance is connected to the external service and it is listening constantly of it.

```
@Component
public class Service extends PollingBot  {


    @Value("${token}")
    private String token;

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage()) {

        }
    }

    public void sendMessageToUser(String message) {
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
        }

    }

}
```

You could see that there is a method called sendMessageToUser which send message. It could not be static because execute method not allow static context. This method could not be separeted to other class. /

So, I have to call this method from other class. However I don't want to create additional instance of Service class otherwise I have two instances which are listen for updates, but I want it is sole class instance doing so.

*I have tried to run a Application Context and run method from it, but it was not worked.*

So, my question is very simple. **How could I run this class non-static(!) method from other class?**

Comment: please read what singleton means.

Comment: @LeTex Interesting idea... I wanted to take Bean from Application Context, but looks like the Singleton could be a nicer approach. Let me check if it works in my case.

Comment: By default all spring managed beans are singletons.

Comment: @Gundamaiah And how could I call Spring Class Bean from other class?

Comment: @vhf you need to use Autowired annotaion to inject the spring bean into another. And then you can call the methods of that bean.

Comment: Why don't you `@Autowired` it? it's a bean, so it's in a Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all spring managed beans are singleton. You need to use @Autowired to inject the bean into other and then you can call the methods of that bean.

```
@Autowired
private Service service;

    public void sendMessage(String message){
    service.sendMessageToUser(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have    NullPointerException adding this code. I will check again maybe something made wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your support. It works now. I have marked Dhruv's answer as marked because he has posted the same answer early. However wish you good luck in all of your projects!

Comment: @vhvf great. How you can tell Dhruv posted earlier than me. If you open any question, old answers will be displayed below. My answer is the first one for this question.

Comment: Aha. I didn't know, sorry. I have choosen your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Autowired annotation to call a method of a bean class(component) in Spring. Also, as mentioned by default beans are singleton in spring so you don't need to worry about creating a single instance explicitly every time.
Try to use the below code in the calling class:

```
@Autowired
private Service service;

public void sendText() {
        service.sendMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have    NullPointerException adding this code. I will check again maybe something made wrong.